# Images not copied to output folder in Pelican

Tags: python, pelican

Inside pelicanconf.py I have:

```
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'extra/CNAME']
```

I have an image file inside images/filename.jpg

When I run `pelican content`, my content rebuilds as expected, but no folder for images is created, nor is my file placed inside the output folder.

How can I get my image file into the output folder, to be used on my site?

Using Pelican 3.5 with Python 2.7.8

Answer (score 3):

You have to put images in "content/images" folder.